# How to deserialize a List of String to a single arg value class?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, jackson-databind

Basically I always want to unwrap my Id class to the parent object but in case of a List<> I can not use the JsonUnwrapped Annotation from the jackson library.

```java
@lombok.Value
public class Response {
  List<MyId> ids;
  // ... other fields
}

@lombok.Value
public class MyId {
  String id;
}
```

```json
{
  "ids": ["id1", "id2"]
  "otherField": {}
}
```

> Working solution with jackson-databind 2.11
>
> ```java
> @lombok.Value
> public class MyId {
>   @JsonValue
>   String id;
>
>   public MyId(final String id) {
>     this.id = id;
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@JsonValue`. From [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html):

> Marker annotation that indicates that the value of annotated accessor (either field or "getter" method [a method with non-void return type, no args]) is to be used as the single value to serialize for the instance, instead of the usual method of collecting properties of value. Usually value will be of a simple scalar type (String or Number), but it can be any serializable type (Collection, Map or Bean).

Usage:

```java
@Value
public class MyId {
    @JsonValue
    String id;
}
```

Complete code:

```java
public class JacksonExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<MyId> myIds = new ArrayList<>();
        MyId id1 = new MyId("one");
        MyId id2 = new MyId("two");
        myIds.add(id1);
        myIds.add(id2);
        Response response = new Response(myIds, "some other field value");
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(response));
    }
}

@Value
class Response {
    List<MyId> ids;
    String otherField;
}

@Value
class MyId {
    @JsonValue
    String id;
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "ids": [
    "one",
    "two"
  ],
  "otherField": "some other field value"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it. It worked as intended **after I manually created a constructor for the class**